no bpy accessable atribute for Workbench Sampling
I'm making a very bodged script to export textures for a game and need some rendered with AA and some without.

When adjusting this setting it comes up in the editor terminal as bpy.data.scenes["Library"].(null) = '8', bpy.data.scenes["Library"].(null) = 'OFF' etc.
This (null) property of the scene can't be accessed in a python script, I am new to blender so may be missing something or do I need to make a github issue.
for now I manually running the script once with AA enable and once with it disabled.
this is the script for refence:

import bpy
import os

# export to blend file location
basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)

if not basedir:
    raise Exception("Blend file is not saved")

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects


bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selection:
    bpy.data.objects[obj.name].hide_render = True

for obj in selection:
    if bpy.data.objects[obj.name].type == "MESH":
        obj.select_set(True)

        # some exporters only use the active object
        view_layer.objects.active = obj

        name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
        fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)
        
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].location = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].hide_render = False
        
        #bpy.data.scenes["Library"].(null) = '8'
        bpy.context.scene.display.shading.light = 'MATCAP'
        bpy.data.scenes["Library"].camera = camera_obj = bpy.data.objects["CameraFront"]
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fn+".front.normal.png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 
        bpy.data.scenes["Library"].camera = camera_obj = bpy.data.objects["CameraTop"]
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fn+".top.normal.png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 
        
        #bpy.data.scenes["Library"].(null) = 'OFF'
        bpy.context.scene.display.shading.light = 'FLAT'
        bpy.data.scenes["Library"].camera = camera_obj = bpy.data.objects["CameraFront"]
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fn+".front.flat.png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 
        bpy.data.scenes["Library"].camera = camera_obj = bpy.data.objects["CameraTop"]
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = fn+".top.flat.png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 
        
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].hide_render = True

        obj.select_set(False)
        
        print("written:", fn)
    else:
        print("Not mesh:"+obj.name)

view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)


Enable Developer Extras and Python Tooltips. Hover the mouse on the element and look for a hint. In this case it is SceneDisplay.render_aa. Then search the docs. To see where you can access the class SceneDisplay with the attribute render_aa see the References section. In this case it is Scene.display.
bpy.context.scene.display.render_aa = '16'


Can also use Edit Source to open the .py responsible for the UI drawing.

Some elements are obscure and not in the docs or written in C and not available for the Python API.
